# Finding the total area of two regions determined by dividing a quarter-circular arc into five congruent parts

Tags: geometry, triangles

I need some help for this problem.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort makes a poor impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Comment: You should use formula of circular segment area

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu $S= R  \theta=10 \pi  / 2 = 5\pi $

Comment: Circular seqment is not the same as the sector. See Wikipedia about Circular segment.
You should double your quarter of circle with mirroring to the left-side. After that doubled A could be interpreted as difference of two circular segments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Dissect the areas with this diagram:[image]

Comment: you make 'it  difficult I think

Comment: @kebiri5 No, TheBestMagician gave you a good hint, he's not making it difficult.

Comment: he's best magician :)

Answer (score -1):

HINT

If integration can be done, figure out and take it forward

$\phi$ angle of radius to symmetry axis

$$B= \int y\; dx = r^2 \int_{\pi/10} ^{2 \pi/10}\sin ^2\ \phi \;d \phi $$

Comment: Might be overkill